# Differences between multiple pages in one browser, and multiple pages in multiple browsers in puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I’m using puppeteer for scraping content from websites, and I need to open multiple pages. I want to know what are the differences between multiple pages in one browser, and multiple pages in multiple browsers?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot run multiples tabs individualy, even with threads using Selenium.**

Opening multiples pages at the same time requires giving one WebDriver entity to EACH of your thread (if you run them in parallel).
This will consume a bit more memory but it's the only workaround if you really need to manage multiple tabs at once.